# how many webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a web service that looks like this:

```cs
public class TheService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
  [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
  public string GetData(string Param1, string Param2) { ... }
}
```

In other words, it's contained in one class and in there, I have one public method and there is another private method that does a read to the database.

The issue I'm facing is in terms of scalability. I'm building a web app that should work for 1,000 daily users and each user will do about 300-500 calls a day to the web service and so that's about 300,000 to 500,000 requests per day. I need to add 9 more calls to the web service. Some of these calls will involve database writes.

My question is this: am I better off creating 9 separate web services or continue with the one service I have and add the other methods. Or may be something different and better. I'm planning to deploy the application on Azure so I'm not really concerned about hardware, just the application side of things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't base my decision off the volume, or for performance/scalability reasons. You won't get much if any performance benefit from keeping them lumped together or separating them.  Any grouping or filtering that can be done while the services are grouped one way can also be done with the services grouped the other way.  The ability to partition between servers will be the same, too.

**Design**

Instead I would focus on trying to make your code understandable and maintainable.  Group your services how they make the most sense architecturally within your program.  Keep them logically grouped how they make the most sense to be grouped, from a problem-domain perspective (as opposed to a solution domain perspective).

Since you're free to group them how you want, I recommend you read up on [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), which is a set of guiding principles for creating software architecture.

One of the principles listed that is particularly important is the [Interface Segregation Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), which can be defined by `the notion that "many client specific interfaces are better than one general purpose interface."`

**Performance and scalability**

Since you mentioned performance and scalability being a concern, I recommend you follow this plan:

- Determine how long you can wait until you can patch/maintain the software
- Determine your expected load, including both average and peak load-per-time (you've determined the average), and how much you expect this traffic to grow over time (specifically over the period you can go without patching/maintaining the software)
- Create a model describing exactly which calls will be done and in which ratios (per time and per server)
- Create automation that mirrors these models as closely as you can.  Try to model both average and peak traffic, and surpassing your highest scale traffic
- Profile your code, DB, network traffic, and disk traffic while running this automation
- Determine the bottlenecks, and if they are within acceptable tolerance
- Optimize your bottlenecks (as required), and repeat from the profiling step forward
- The next release of your software, repeat from the top to add scenarios/load/automation
- Perform regression testing using your existing tests, altered to fit the new scale

Comment: Ok, cool; it's not splitting or combining the methods that'll make a difference but I'll split them anyway just to make it look pretty. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the web methods into several web services won't help you here; load balancing will.

Comment: @frenchie: precisely, splitting the web methods won't make any difference.

Comment: @Icarus - running different Web Service endpoints on different roles allows for independent scale-out, as Igorek suggested.

Answer (score 2):

The number of web services will not have any affect on scalability of the app.

Finding your bottlenecks will help scalability.  If you're bottleneck is the DB, you may need to find ways to tune your queries, partition your data across more stores, etc...  If you're bottleneck is CPU on the web services (web roles in azure), then adding more than one web role to your cluster will help.  Azure supports that.

But, simply don't start adding roles.  Understand where your bottlenecks are.  Measure, profile and tune.

Azure has devfabric and IIS locally to help you profile locally as well.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the web-services into multiple web roles because of physical constraints and not necessarily due to logical layout may be worth considering because:

Using Azure you can scale out your Roles independently of one another.  This means that IF different web methods need to scale in different patterns (ie: your first web method has the biggest volume in the mornings and after lunch and your other two web methods have the biggest volume in the evening and during the night), and the last 2 web methods are usually flat throughout the day, it very well maybe worth it to split your methods across Roles by scalability constraints and not by logical constraints.

By increasing/decreasing the servers allocated to each method independently you maybe able to fine-tune your optimal power vs. need with a much greater precision.

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Actually, creating separate Web Services, as Igorek suggested, will provide much more granular scale-out. In that scenario, you can deploy different Web Services to different Roles, each role getting its own set of instances (along with the option to create different instance sizes per role). Windows Azure will load-balance across all the instances of a Role.

So from a granularity standpoint:

- Least granular: Combine all methods into a single Web Service, hosted on a single Role. As you scale out to multiple instances, all service method requests are load-balanced across all instances. Because you're combining everything into one Role, you will find this to be optimized for cost: You can run all Web Services code in a single instance (really 2 instances to give yourself SLA).
- More granular: Create separate Web Services, each with their own methods, and host on the same Role (allows you to exercise SOLID principles, as Merlyn described). Same basic performance characteristics as the first option, as all requests are still load-balanced across the same set of instances.
- Most granular: Create separate Web Services, each with their own methods, and host each Web Service endpoint on a separate Role, allowing for independent VM sizing and scale-out of each Web Service endpoint. This option has a higher runtime cost to it, as you now have a minimum of one instance per Web Service endpoint (again, 2 instances in a real world, live application).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about exact your case, but moving expensive (from CPU/DB point of view) tasks to separate Worker Role usually are good solution for Azure. In that case you will have one WebRole with services that will receive requests (it will be light weight, so you sjould not have many Instances for it) and create tasks for Worker Roles and one or few Worker Roles that will process that tasks - #1 Worker Roles can be created per kind of task (to group similar actions like reading/writing data to DB) or #2 one Worker Role can handle any type of task. I don't see any benefits in #2, because to get the same behavior you can just create one WebRole with many instances and handle all there. So you will have ability to control processing time by adding/removing Worker Roles.

As other people suggested - using Azure platform by itself will not make app scalable, especially if you are using SQL Azure, you will need to implement sharding or add many DBes to avoid one big DB for all requests.

I don't know if that's related to this questing, but just to let you know - Azure is dropping connections which are not active during 60 sec (I did not find some way to increase that timeout, you can Google this problem). This may be an issue is you are porting web-services to Azure and your responses can reach 60 seconds. One way to avoid it is keeping connection active, which is pretty simple if clients know about this "feature".

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info; I don't think I have any tasks that last more than 60s but always good to know.